# Getting the correct colours for pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using pcolormesh to show the results from some algorithm I am running.
I create the usual mesh for some `x_min, x_max`, etc., and define my color map

```
h = (x_max - x_min) / 1000.
xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(x_min, x_max, h), numpy.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
colours = ("blue", "green", "red")
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(colours)
```

and then do `plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.7, cmap=cmap)`, where Z is the result of my prediction (it could be any 0, 1 or 2 value, it does not matter).

Say `Z = numpy.zeros(xx.shape)` I should see everything blue, `Z = numpy.ones(xx.shape)` I should see green, and `Z = 2*numpy.ones(xx.shape)` I should see red, or so I thought. Instead, I always see blue.
If I add these lines:

```
  Z[0] = 0
  Z[1] = 1
  Z[2] = 2
```

everything works as expected. It looks as if the result does not have all the possible results (0,1,2) then it defaults to use only the first color, blue, even if the result is all 2s, and I want red.

How can I force it to have the colours I desire, i.e. blue for 0, green for 1 and red for 2, in every case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clim` to fix your colorbar.

```
plt.clim(0, 3)
```

That will force 0 to be blue, 1 to be green, 2 to be red.

Answer (score 2):

You have to normalize ColorMap:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

x_max = 100.
x_min = 0.
y_max = 100.
y_min = 0.
h = (x_max - x_min) / 5.
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max+h, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max+h, h))
Z = np.random.randint(3, size=(5,5))
# define color map & norm it
colours = (["blue", "green", "red"])
cmap = ListedColormap(colours)
bounds=[0,1,2,np.max(Z)+1] # discrete values of Z
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
# for colorbar
ticks  = [.5,1.5,2.5]
labels = ['0','1','2']
# plot
pcm = plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.7, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cb = plt.colorbar(pcm, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, ticks=ticks)
cb.set_ticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Z array:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 2 2 0]
 [1 1 1 2 2]]
```

Comment: Both great answers that both deserved +1, though I ended up using clim.